# Rails: Is there away to get the Date object that is the closest Monday to today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

Given a date, how do I find the nearest Monday in Rails?

I know I can do things like:

Date.tomorrow
Date.today

Is there something like Date.nearest :monday ?

Comment: do you need to go in both directions? i.e. if it is tuesday, go to yesterday but if it is friday go to the next monday?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [commercial](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-commercial) method on the Date object will let you do this.  This example will get you the next Monday.

```
Date.commercial(Date.today.year, 1+Date.today.cweek, 1)
```

If you need the next or previous Monday, whichever is closest, you can do:

```
Date.commercial(Date.today.year, Date.today.cwday.modulo(4)+Date.today.cweek, 1)
```

I can't execute this right now, so forgive me if there are syntax errors.

Comment: `.divmod(4)` returns an array. You could use `.divmod(4)[1]` or `.modulo(4)` instead ;D

Comment: @PeterWong thanks for pointing that out.  It's been corrected.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the long delay in response, holiday! :-)

Answer (score 14):

It's a little bit tricky, but not so hard to calculate.

Use [`ActiveSupport::DateAndTimeCalculations#end_of_week`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_and_time/calculations.rb#L190-L192) to calculate end of a week, this method accepts a `start_day` parameter that is used to indicate start day of the week (it's `:monday` by default). They even have implemented [`sunday`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_and_time/calculations.rb#L197-L199) method.

The trick is the following: if you want to calculate closest Monday, you may calculate it as a end of the week which starts on Tuesday (Tue => 1st day, Wed => 2nd day, ..., Mon => 7th day which is also end of the week).

So all you need to do is:

```
# it will return current date if today is Monday and nearest Monday otherwise
Date.today.end_of_week(:tuesday)
```

Comment: This answer along with use of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21199096/1612469) article, was the best approach for me

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old thread but it's always nice to keep it current for future seekers.

Let's assume today is say Friday the 19th of August. All I do to get my nearest Monday is this:

```
monday = Date.today.monday
```

Then from there you can go back a week or forward a week like this:

```
last_monday = monday.last_week
next_monday = monday.next_week
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want both directions: `Date.today.beginning_of_week + 7*(Date.today.wday/5)`

Answer (score 1):

Untested, so you might need to finetune, but here you go:

```
def Date.nearest_monday
  today = Date.today
  wday  = today.wday
  if wday > 4 # over the half of the week
    today + (7 - wday) # next monday
  else
    today - (1 + wday) # previous monday
  end
end
```