# Monkey-patch Date class for next_<weekday> methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, monkeypatching

In my Rails app I need to get the dates for the next occurrence of a particular weekday starting from some other date. So basically I need `date.next_monday`, `date.next_wednesday` type functions. I don't think these exist in standard Ruby libraries so I decided to monkey patch the Date class like so:

```
class Date
  weekdays = [:sunday, :monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday]
  weekdays.each do |weekday|
    method_name = "next_" + weekday.to_s
    send :define_method, method_name do
      tmp_date = self + 1
      until tmp_date.send((weekday.to_s + "?").to_sym)
        tmp_date = tmp_date + 1
      end
      tmp_date
    end
  end
end
```

This seems to work fine.
My questions are:

1. Did I not need to do all that? (Is there some way to get next_ that I'm not thinking of?
2. If what I did is necessary, is there a better way to get the weekdays array?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider commercial method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514988/rails-is-there-away-to-get-the-date-object-that-is-the-closest-monday-to-today

Comment: That looks useful. The other answer to this question had useful links too, esp the tickle gem. But that answer was gone before I could up vote it :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` class defines a `DAYNAMES` constant ([as well as a number of other useful constants](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#constants-list)) that you could use to replace your array.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there _had_ to be something ;)