# Ruby/Rails - Convert Integer to Day of Week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I know you can use [wday](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/wday) to return the day of the week as an integer value:

```
 Date.new(2001,2,3).wday           #=> 6 (a.k.a. "Saturday")
```

But, is there a method to do this the opposite way, in reverse?

Like:

```
 day_of_week(6)                        #=> "Saturday"
```

Or is this something I would convert on my own?

Thanks.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `Date::DAYNAMES` array has that information:

```
Date::DAYNAMES[6]
# => "Saturday"
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use a `proc` or `lambda` because I wouldn't want to type this `Date::DAYNAMES[d]` repeatedly.

```
day = Proc.new { |d| Date::DAYNAMES[d] }
day.call(6)
# => "Saturday"
```

Or even more succinct as a `lambda`:

```
day = ->num { Date::DAYNAMES[num] }
day.(6)
# => "Saturday"
```

Just remember to: `require 'Date'`

Comment: If typing really bothers you that much, `days = Date::DAYNAMES` -- accessible as `days[6]` -- is a more straightforward solution.